# Codeigniter-returning value to output in table with foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, html-table

I am using Codeigniter, and I want to return some information for an advisor. For some reason, the model isn't returning anything from the database (I'm assuming since I placed text throughout the table in view and nothing came up). The query calls information from two different tables, and I used the query directly in the database to make sure it works.

At this point, I'm sure that it is something small that I'm missing. Any insight is appreciated.

**Model**

```
function profileInfo($user_id, $user_type)
{
    if($user_type == 'advisor')
    {
        $this->db->select('user_fullname, CWID, user_name, user_email, user_phone, major, office_loc');
        $this->db->from('users, advisor');
        $this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('users.user_id = advisor.user_id');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }


    elseif($user_type == 'advisee')
    {
        $this->db->select('user_fullname, CWID, user_name, user_email, user_phone, major, classification');
        $this->db->from('users, advisee');
        $this->db->where('users.user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('users.user_id = advisee.user_id');

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }


    else
    {
        $this->db->select('user_fullname, CWID, user_name, user_email, user_phone');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
    function profilePage()
    {
        $CWID = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $userType = $this->session->userdata('user_type');
        $data = array('view' => 'viewProfile', 'userid' => $CWID, 'usertype' => $userType, 'user_info' => $this->Users_model->profileInfo($CWID, $userType));
        $this->load->view('admin', $data);
    }
```

**View**

```
    <?php if($usertype =='advisor'): ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ($user_info as $row): ?>
        <tr>    
            <th>Name:  </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_fullname?></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <th>CWID: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->CWID ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_name ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_email ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_phone ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Major: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->major ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Office Location: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->office_loc ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>    

<!--Provides view for a user that is an advisee-->
<?php elseif($usertype =='advisee'): ?>
    <table> 
    <?php foreach ($user_info as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Name: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_fullname ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>CWID: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->CWID ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_name ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_email ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_phone ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Major: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->major ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Classification: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->classification ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
    <!--Provides view for all other user types-->
<?php else: ?>
    <table> 
    <?php foreach ($user_info as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <th>Name: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_fullname ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>CWID: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->CWID ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>User Name: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_name ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_email ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone: </th>
            <td><?php echo $row->user_phone ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Are you completely positive that the `profileInfo` is returning a result set?

Comment: Sorry, I actually figured it out. It wasn't. I'm working in a group, and didn't realize the session variables had been changed. Thank you anyway!